# SQL Server : stored procedure returns nothing

Tags: sql-server

There is table `Products`

[image]

I created a stored procedure:

[image]

and then I try to execute it

[image]

but I get nothing

[image]

[image]

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: It means procedure was executed correctly. It is the same as explicitly adding `RETURN 0;` at the end of SP. Describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: but why I didn't get other parameters like id, price and categoryID? I mean, I get only name but not other parameters http://i.stack.imgur.com/oklmV.png

Comment: Look at your select statement, probably WHERE name=@name is always false. That's why. Secondly what is the point of returning arguments you pass to SP.

Comment: Return `SELECT id, name, price, Category ID` not `SELECT @id, @name ...`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works!

Comment: One more thing: `@name NVARCHAR(100) = 0`, maybe better set it to NULL or if it need to be 0  make it explicit `@name NVARCHAR(100) = N'0'`

Comment: Thank you for this tip, I'll use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change SELECT statement. Now you are returning, what are you passing to SP.

```
 // Incorrect, you just pass it as SP arguments
 SELECT @id, @name, @price, @categoryID
 FROM Products
 WHERE name = @name;


 // Actual data, retrieved from table
 SELECT id, name, price, categoryID
 FROM Products
 WHERE name = @name;
```